# Creation of inner class instance from another class (but the same package)

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

The following classes are defined in the default package.

Outer.java:

```
public class Outer {

    public class Inner {

    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import Outer.Inner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer.Inner inner = new Inner();
    }

}
```

I get:

> Inner cannot be resolved to a type

I do know it is possible to instantiate an inner class from within the same package.
What's wrong and how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Inner class should be static (otherwise, you will need an Outer instance in order to create an Inner instance, and that's bad design), and you should use

```
Outer.Inner inner = new Outer.Inner();
```

And no, you should NEVER put classes in the default package.